# How can i make all three console.log into a single line?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

// code

```
const arr1 = [17, 21, 34];
const printForecast = function (arr1) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    console.log(`${arr1[i]} C on day ${arr1.indexOf(arr1[i]) + 1}`);
  }
};

printForecast(arr1);
```

// I want an output like this-->
17 C on day 1
21 C on day 2
34 C on day 3

Comment: Construct the string inside the loop. Assign it to a variable and then print it outside the for loop.

Comment: `${arr1.indexOf(arr1[i]) + 1}` will give you unexpected results as soon as there is a duplicate value in the array. Do you mean `${i + 1}`?

Comment: Could you provide more details?

Answer (score 1):

1. Your function should ideally be returning a value.
2. Use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate over the array, create a new array of strings, and [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) that up into a new string before you return it.

```js
const arr1 = [17, 21, 34];

function getForecast(arr1) {
  return arr1.map((num, i) => {
    return `${num} C on day ${i + 1}`;
  }).join(', ');
};

console.log(getForecast(arr1));
```

Answer (score 1):

Construct the string inside the loop. Assign it to a variable and then print it outside the for loop.

```js
const arr1 = [17, 21, 34];

const printForecast = function(arr1) {
  let string = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    string += `${arr1[i]} C on day ${arr1.indexOf(arr1[i]) + 1}, `;
  }
  console.log(string);
};

printForecast(arr1);
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
const arr1 = [17, 21, 34];

arr1.forEach((item, index) => {
  console.log(`${item} C on day ${index + 1}`);
});
```

Comment: I want all the console logs printed on the same line.